hong-kong action movie from 70s or 80s with a heist and a crossbow
Although I haven't seen this movie in full I do remember one particular scene: man shoots a crossbow bolt with a string attached. He slides down on it to some skyscraper building and attacks some mafia guys. He takes a briefcase and runs on a motorbike. This is classic Hong-Kong action flick from 70s or 80s.

This sounds like Aces Go Places (1982), also known as Mad Mission

A "James Bond" type burglar named King Kong tries to redeem himself and joins forces with Albert "Baldy" Au, a bumbling police detective from the states, to try to track down a rare set of stolen luscious diamonds before it ends up in the hands of a notorious European gangster named "White Gloves." 

  
  
  
  

Watch the trailer on YouTube

